# MySQL exporting WordPress posts with related meta data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, export

I'm using the WP-Property plugin for an estate agents site. They want to use RightMove to display their properties as well, so I'm looking for a way to export the post type 'property' with all its related meta data.

Most of the data for a property is in the posts table, but things like the number of bedrooms, price etc are in the post meta table.

I'm not much of a back end coder, so I think I need an SQL query that will join the two tables together?

I have to convert it to a BLM file for RightMove, but I'm taking it one stage at a time, so getting the data I need out is what I need to do.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to write a join where the post_id of postmeta table is equal to the id of posts table

Comment: I don't suppose anyone could give me a rough idea of what the query might be?